# How to start to understand Walter Benjamin's work?

Tags: critical-theory, art

How should I go about starting to understand Walter Benjamin's work? I don't have any special goal, but want to get to grips with *The Arcades Project*. How?

Just a quote from something I've not read, that drew me into doing so.

> The Arcades expose reads like a series of **captions**...

- Walter Benjamin: Modernity - Page 131

I looked at parts of it, but am lost as to what he's doing.

Comment: You can see e.g. Esther Leslie, [Walter Benjamin, (Reaktion Books, 2008)](https://books.google.it/books?id=12bC8yjZllgC&printsec=frontcover) with some comments on the *Arcade Project* and ref in Biblio to some deficated books on it.

Comment: there's a lot about bejamin, and some of it seems useless... that's why i asked @MauroALLEGRANZA

Comment: @another_name What about it seems useless? (Put another way, what do you want that you aren't getting from those sources? This will help refine the question.)

Comment: @NoahSchweber good comment, thanks. i want to know what makes his work, work, and nothing i've seen answers that question. so if someone were to say e.g. "fragmentation and his erudition generates X because Y" that could be a **starting point** << (rather than e.g. a description of the work)